# Is the elementary definition of a scalar misleading?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, tensors, scalar-fields

An elementary definition of a scalar is that it is ''a quantity having only magnitude''.

I've been trying to reconcile this statement that I've always accepted with (1) the more exact definition of a scalar and (2) the definition of magnitude in Euclidean space. I am struggling with a particular paradox that I've tried to explain to myself in a brief note. I'm not convinced that my reasoning nor my conclusion are entirely valid. This is what I wrote:

> From the first introduction to vectors in secondary school, up to
>   fundamental courses at the collegiate level, a frequently encountered
>   statement is:
>
> ''A vector is a quantity having both magnitude and direction. A scalar
>   is a quantity having only magnitude.''
>
> Though a useful introduction the the concept of vectors, the problem
>   with the above statement is that it is misleading.
>
> In the context of applications to mechanics, the further discussion is
>   restricted to Euclidean vectors.
>
> First, consider the more precise definition of a scalar; namely a
>   quantity which is invariant under all possible rotational
>   transformations of the coordinate system in which it is described.
>
> In Euclidean space, by definition the magnitude (Euclidean norm) is always
>   positive. Also, the magnitude of a Euclidean vector is invariant under all
>   possible transformations of the coordinate system in which it is
>   described. Therefore magnitude is a scalar.
>
> Now consider that there are two vectors, $\mathbf{a}$ and
>   $\mathbf{b}$. The difference of the lengths of these two vectors,
>   $\Delta = \left\|\mathbf{b}\right\| - \left\|\mathbf{a}\right\|$ can
>   be negative. Yet $\Delta$ is also invariant with rotation of the coordinate
>   system, and is therefore a scalar. But by definition, if it is
>   less than zero, it is not a magnitude ($\Delta$ does, of course,
>   *have* a magnitude --its absolute value--in addition to a sign).
>
> The above example suggests that ''all magnitudes are scalars, but not
>   all scalars are magnitudes''.
>
> A more accurate wording of the classic introductory definition of
>   vectors and scalars might therefore be,
>
> ''A vector is a quantity having both magnitude and direction. A scalar
>   is a quantity having magnitude *and a sign*.''

Is what I am saying correct and/or are there errors or fallacies in my reasoning?

EDIT This might be semantics, but it is possible to interpret the elementary definition as "''A vector is a quantity having both magnitude and direction. A scalar is a quantity having only magnitude **(and not direction)**.'' In which case it would not preclude a sign, and would make sense.

Comment: When they say "a scalar is a quantity having only magnitude", the term "magnitude" is not a term that has been given a precise definition. They are only speaking loosely. It seems that you are assuming a specific definition of the word "magnitude" which was not intended.

Comment: It's absolutely true that a scalar can have a negative sign. It's also relatively common to have complex scalars which have a direction in complex space. Many fields are scalars under spatial rotations but transform under internal transformations. I'd stick to the technical definition now that you know it. The other is a useful simplification for teaching beginners but doesn't quite get to the heart of the matter.

Comment: There are other geometries besides that of Euclidean space, and there are other “magnitudes” besides Euclidean distance between two points. E.g., in relativity, the “distance” between two different events—vectors in Minkowski spacetime—can be either positive *or* negative.

Comment: Certainly @amd. I based my argument on the following statements on the [Magnitude (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitude_(mathematics)#Numbers) Wikipedia page: (1) The magnitude of any number is usually called its "absolute value" or "modulus", denoted by |x| and (2) The magnitude or length of a Euclidean vector space is most commonly defined as its Euclidean norm (or Euclidean length). I agree that alternative definitions of magnitude, or extension to other vector spaces, could drastically impact my argument.

Answer (score 0):

The point of the elementary definition is to build physical intuition for common elementary examples, which turn out also to be useful examples of more general phenomena.

Of course the loose definition will not do when you start pinning down subtleties connected with the real numbers, and when we start defining vector spaces by their properties, rather than imagining vectors as arrows in physical three-dimensional space.

But physical space is what we might call a motivating example - it is one key reason why we care about making a precise definition, and creating a model (mathematical structure) with useful properties.